# Form submit inside Ajax JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have to submit a form inside the Ajax.
I'm receiving 'form.submit is not a function' JQuery error.

```
$("#form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        type: "required",
        groups: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        type: "Type is required",
        groups: {
            required: "Group is required" 
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check_exists.php",
            data: {
                  groups: $( "#groups" ).val(),
                  type: $( "#type" ).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
              if(data == "true") {
                    form.submit();  // It shows form.submit is not a function
              } else {
                    // Displays error
              }

            }
        });        
    }
});
```

When I give the form.submit() function above the Ajax, It works!
Then how do I submit this form inside the Ajax success function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey u can use the arrow function feature here

```
$("#form").validate({    
    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        type: "required",
        groups: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        type: "Type is required",
        groups: {
            required: "Group is required" 
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check_exists.php",
            data: {
                  groups: $( "#groups" ).val(),
                  type: $( "#type" ).val()
            },
            success: (data) => {
              if(data == "true") {
                    form.submit();
              } else {
                    // Displays error
              }

            }
        });        
    }
});
```

It will bind the context of the callback function to submitHandler function

Comment: Sorry, Not working! I'm receiving same 'form.submit is not a function' JQuery error

Comment: console.log(form) in submitHandler .. what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the scope of the `form` variable:

```
var form_to_be_submitted = null;
$("#form").validate({    
    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        type: "required",
        groups: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        type: "Type is required",
        groups: {
            required: "Group is required" 
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form_to_be_submitted = form;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check_exists.php",
            data: {
                  groups: $( "#groups" ).val(),
                  type: $( "#type" ).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
              if(data == "true") {
                    form_to_be_submitted.submit();  // It shows form.submit is not a function
              } else {
                    // Displays error
              }

            }
        });        
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, Not working! I'm receiving same **'form_to_be_submitted.submit is not a function'** JQuery error

Comment: did you check the value of `form_to_be_submitted`? what does it output?

Comment: I have checked form_to_be_submitted value inside the ajax and above ajax. Both alerts same value